# SharePoint CSOM token expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, csom

We have an ASP.NET MVC web app that uses Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM from Nuget to connect to a SharePoint site. It works fine until the ACS token we acquired expires in 1 hour 5 minutes.

The basic functionality I see in the code we got from the library (TokenHelper.cs and SharePointContext.cs) is that it stores the SpContext in the session and reuses it every time it needs to request something from SharePoint site. Once the token expires, it needs to go through a new authentication. I thought the component should use the RenewAccessTokenIfNeeded to refresh it but it does not.

Where and how would we call the method RenewAccessTokenIfNeeded? If that is not the way, what should we do to keep the user signed in with a token?